# Process exited before request Completed

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using a lambda function to take an image from a bucket, duplicate it into another bucket. Then take the original image and resize it and copy it into the other bucket as well. Then after this is done, delete the original photo from the original bucket.

Start:

Bucket1 = image.jpg
Bucket2 = empty

END:

Bucket1 = empty
Bucket2 = imagecopy.jpg, imageresized.jpg

```
// dependencies
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm')
            .subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.
var util = require('util');

// constants
var MAX_WIDTH  = 100;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    var dstBucket = srcBucket + "resized";
    var dstKey    = "resized-" + srcKey;

    // Sanity check: validate that source and destination are different buckets.
    if (srcBucket == dstBucket) {
        callback("Source and destination buckets are the same.");
        return;
    }

    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        callback("Could not determine the image type.");
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1];
    if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
        callback('Unsupported image type: ${imageType}');
        return;
    }

    // Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },
        function transform(response, next) {
            gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                    MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
                    MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                );
                var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
                var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

                // Transform the image buffer in memory.
                this.resize(width, height)
                    .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        } else {
                            next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                        }
                    });
            });
            },
            function upload(contentType, data, next) {
                // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
                s3.putObject({
                        Bucket: dstBucket,
                        Key: dstKey,
                        Body: data,
                        ContentType: contentType
                    },
                    next);
            },
            function copyImage(next) {
              s3.copyObject({
                  CopySource: srcBucket + '/' + srcKey,
                  Bucket: dstBucket,
                  Key: srcKey
                }, next)
            },
            function deleteOrig(next) {
              s3.deleteObject({
                Bucket: srcBucket,
                Key: srcKey
              })
            }
        ], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(
                    'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
                    ' due to an error: ' + err
                );
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
                    ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
                );
            }

            callback(null, "message");
        }
    );
};
```

LOGS:

```
START RequestId: b9ed83e2-4048-4434-bb5c-adf511b6200b Version: $LATEST
2019-01-31T10:39:52.312Z    b9ed83e2-4048-4434-bb5c-adf511b6200b    Reading options from event:
 { Records: 
   [ { eventVersion: '2.0',
       eventSource: 'aws:s3',
       awsRegion: 'us-west-2',
       eventTime: '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
       eventName: 'ObjectCreated:Put',
       userIdentity: { principalId: 'AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE' },
       requestParameters: { sourceIPAddress: '127.0.0.1' },
       responseElements: 
        { 'x-amz-request-id': 'C3D13FE58DE4C810',
          'x-amz-id-2': 'FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD' },
       s3: 
        { s3SchemaVersion: '1.0',
          configurationId: 'testConfigRule',
          bucket: 
           { name: 'ciansource',
             ownerIdentity: { principalId: 'A3NL1KOZZKExample' },
             arn: 'arn:aws:s3:::ciansource' },
          object: 
           { key: 'football.jpg',
             size: 1024,
             eTag: 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e',
             versionId: '096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko' } } } ] }
2019-01-31T10:39:52.617Z    b9ed83e2-4048-4434-bb5c-adf511b6200b    TypeError: callback.call is not a function
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:364:18)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
END RequestId: b9ed83e2-4048-4434-bb5c-adf511b6200b
REPORT RequestId: b9ed83e2-4048-4434-bb5c-adf511b6200b  Duration: 344.41 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 39 MB  
RequestId: b9ed83e2-4048-4434-bb5c-adf511b6200b Process exited before completing request
```

Comment: can you add the logs you're seeing on CloudWatch logs ?  This will help to understand the execution path into the function.  Thanks

Comment: @SébastienStormacq Done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for having added the log.  It is difficult to say just by reading your code.  So I refactor it using the new `async`/`await` keywords in ES2017 and Nodev8.

I tested this code on my laptop and it works as expected.

In addition, it has the following advantage :

- it is easier to read (developers spend much more time reading code that writing code)
- it is easier to test as each function can be tested separatly
- it is easier to reuse as each function can be used from other functions or modules.

Give it a try.

If, for some reason, you can not use ES2017 or Node v8, I would suggest to add `console.log()` in each of your waterfall functions to understand where it breaks.

```
// dependencies
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true }); // Enable ImageMagick integration.

// constants
var MAX_WIDTH  = 100;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

// added for testing on laptop - you NEED TO delete this to run it from Lambda
const event =  {
    "Records" : [
        {
            "s3" : {
                "bucket" : {
                    "name" : "test-so-sst"
                },
                "object" : {
                    "key" : "image.jpg"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

async function  download(srcBucket, srcKey) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getObject({
            Bucket: srcBucket,
            Key: srcKey
        }, (error, data) => {
            if (error) { 
                console.log(error); reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
};

async function transform(imageType, image) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        gm(image).size(function(err, size) {
            // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
            var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
                MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
            );
            var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
            var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

            // Transform the image buffer in memory.
            this.resize(width, height)
                .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(buffer);
                    }
                });
        }); 
    });
}

async function upload(dstBucket, dstKey, contentType, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Stream the transformed image to a different S3 bucket.
        s3.putObject({
                Bucket: dstBucket,
                Key: dstKey,
                Body: data,
                ContentType: contentType
            }, (error, data) => {
                if (error) { 
                    console.log(error); reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }    
            });
    });
}

async function  copyImage(srcBucket, srcKey, dstBucket) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.copyObject({
            CopySource: srcBucket + '/' + srcKey,
            Bucket: dstBucket,
            Key: srcKey
        }, (error, data) => {
            if (error) { 
                console.log(error); reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
};

async function  deleteOrig(srcBucket, srcKey) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.deleteObject({
            Bucket: srcBucket,
            Key: srcKey
        }, (error, data) => {
            if (error) { 
                console.log(error); reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
};


exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", JSON.stringify(event, null,2));
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    var dstBucket = srcBucket + "-resized";
    var dstKey    = "resized-" + srcKey;

    // Sanity check: validate that source and destination are different buckets.
    if (srcBucket == dstBucket) {
        callback("Source and destination buckets are the same.");
        return;
    }

    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        callback("Could not determine the image type.");
        return;
    }
    var imageType = typeMatch[1];
    if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
        callback(`Unsupported image type: ${imageType}`);
        return;
    }

    // Download the image from S3, transform, and upload to a different S3 bucket.
    try {
        let responseDownload  = await download(srcBucket, srcKey);
        let responseTransform = await transform(imageType, responseDownload.Body);
        let responseUpload    = await upload(dstBucket, dstKey, responseDownload.ContentType, responseTransform);
        let responseCopy      = await copyImage(srcBucket, srcKey, dstBucket);
        let responseDelete    = await deleteOrig(srcBucket, srcKey);    
        console.log(
            'Successfully resized ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
            ' and uploaded to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey
        );
    } catch (error) {
        const message = 'Unable to resize ' + srcBucket + '/' + srcKey +
        ' and upload to ' + dstBucket + '/' + dstKey +
        ' due to an error: ' + error;
        console.error(message);
        callback(error, message);
    }

    callback(null, "success");
};

//to test from my laptop - you can safely remove this before to deploy to Lambda
exports.handler(event, null, (error, message) => {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    console.log(message);
})
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much.